# Python Error - Float object is not iterable error

Tags: python, iterable

I am quite new to python, and am still trying learn the ropes. I am trying to calculate Zero-Coupon bonds, however, seem to get the following error

```
float' object is not iterable
```

This is my code so far, I assume there is something wrong with my sum function, but any advice would be much appreciated !

```
prices = [98828.9817, 97812.0511, 96937.8969,
          96159.9962, 95269.2339, 94353.5669, 
          93276.0334, 92237.8837, 91261.0455, 
          90214.0597, 89083.9301, 87944.5962, 
          86976.3584, 85928.4188, 84982.5065,
          84248.2589, 83540.8304, 82911.5228,
          82417.0923, 82009.0742, 81633.1317,
          81287.3700, 81087.7608, 80919.5136, 
          80780.7515, 80669.7282, 80584.8196,
          80524.5143, 80487.4060, 80472.1856]

ytm = [0.04063, 0.04118, 0.04166, 
          0.04209, 0.04258, 0.04310,
          0.04371, 0.04431, 0.04487,
          0.04549, 0.04616, 0.04684,
          0.04743, 0.04807, 0.04866,
          0.04912, 0.04957, 0.04997,
          0.05028, 0.05054, 0.05079,
          0.05101, 0.05114, 0.05125,
          0.05134, 0.05141, 0.05147,
          0.05151, 0.05153, 0.05154]

iterations = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

I = range(len(prices))
FV = 100000
CP = 0.04 * FV

# Zero Coupon Bond
for i in I:
    ZCB = sum(CP/(1+ytm[i])**iterations[i]) + (FV+CP)/((1+ytm[i])**iterations[i])
    print(ZCB)
```

Comment: what's the purpose of using __sum__ in this line __sum(CP/(1+ytm[i])**iterations[i]) + (FV+CP)/((1+ytm[i])**iterations[i])__

Answer (score 0):

sum() always take iterable as its argument
when you write `sum(2)` **This will raise TypeError and will say 2 is not iterable**

similarly in your case
`sum()` **is taking float as its argument so the error "Float object is not iterable"**

`sum([2])` This will work because lists are iterable

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from passing a single `float` to `sum`, which expects an iterable (like a list).

I can't quite tell what your original intent is, since you're mixing both procedural and functional styles. I'd recommend that you either incrementally sum `ZCB` yourself, using the `+=` operator, or else, since all your arguments are the same length, use `numpy` to do vector math on them.

The reason I hesitate to rewrite your code in a functional style is because you're only using `sum()` on the first part of your formula, and I'm not sure whether you meant to sum the entire thing. Leaving your formula alone, the second part will iterate and produce multiple values for ZCB:

```py
import numpy as np
sum(CP/(1+np.array(ytm))**np.array(iterations)) + (FV+CP)/((1+np.array(ytm))**np.array(iterations))
 
array([162407.65073366, 158404.21266146, 154482.50164677, 150656.78642701,
       146896.169642  , 143206.13145474, 139553.99871209, 135986.89550577,
       132528.65334532, 129123.4633484 , 125775.53903412, 122512.19342737,
       119406.9801568 , 116365.77283386, 113461.4536341 , 110755.24145864,
       108160.10924376, 105704.56954205, 103416.55213126, 101263.70203759,
        99213.23619558,  97276.48018957,  95493.00572611,  93807.47916263,
        92215.90751991,  90714.30147789,  89291.81257265,  87951.62415916,
        86689.91102085,  85496.36006465])
```